# EventListener for parentNode For Multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm doing my project right now and want to add some feature on the table, which is delete button for the user, and the confirmation window pops up to make sure that the admin wants to delete the user from the table with 'yes' and 'no' button, if we click 'yes' then the user is deleted when 'no' the the confirmation window disappears. here's the code. I'm able to show the confirmation window but unable to close it or make it disappear again.

any ideas?

```js
const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('.trashIcon');
const buttonYes = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonYes');
const buttonNo = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonNo');

function openWindow() {
  this.parentNode.querySelector('.confirmWindow').classList.remove('hidden');
  this.classList.add('hidden');
}

function closeDeleteWindow(e) {
    //this is where my problem is
e.currentTarget.querySelector('.confirmWindow').classList.add('hidden');

    this.classList.add('hidden');
}

for (let i=0; i < deleteButton.length; i++){
  deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click', openWindow);
}

for (let i=0; i < buttonNo.length; i++){
  buttonNo[i].addEventListener('click', closeDeleteWindow);
}
```

```css
table {
    font-family: Nunito Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  td, th {
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 115%;
    letter-spacing:0.01em;
  }
  
  thead th{
    padding: 16px!important;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #abb3c2;
  }
  
  .header{
    background-color: #05111A;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .table-row {
    height: 65px;
  }
  
  .table-download {
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #05111A;
  }
  
  .table-download i {
    margin-right: 3px;
  }

  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  .trashIcon {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabelle.css">
    <link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th scope="col">UserID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email Address</th>
        <th scope="col">Standort</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="table-row">
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Audrey Mckinney</td>
        <td>lisa.watson@example.com</td>
        <td>Mannheim</td>
        <td>
          <div class="confirmWindow hidden">
            <p class="confirmWindowText">Are you sure want to delete?</p>
            <button class="buttonYes">Yes</button>
            <button class="buttonNo">No</button>
          </div>
        <button class="trashIcon"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" ></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-row">
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Savannah Howard</td>
        <td>jeff.brown@example.com</td>
        <td>Marburg</td>
        <td>
          <div class="confirmWindow hidden">
            <p class="confirmWindowText">Are you sure want to delete?</p>
            <button class="buttonYes">Yes</button>
            <button class="buttonNo">No</button>
          </div>
        <button class="trashIcon"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" ></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<script src="tabelle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `e.currentTarget` is the button itself, it doesn't contain the "window". The window is `e.target.closest('.confirmWindow')`.

Comment: thanks for the help @teemu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
e.currentTarget.querySelector('.confirmWindow').classList.add('hidden');
```

is looking for an element with the class `confirmWindow` inside the "No" button element. We're trying to hide the confirm window which is a parent of the button, so obviously this won't work.

An easier way is just to simply reference the parent with the `parentElement` property.

To show the trash icon, we can use the `nextElementSibling` property to get the next sibling.

```js
const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('.trashIcon');
const buttonYes = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonYes');
const buttonNo = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonNo');

function openWindow() {
  this.parentNode.querySelector('.confirmWindow').classList.remove('hidden');
  this.classList.add('hidden');
}

function closeDeleteWindow(e) {
  e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('hidden');
  e.target.parentElement.classList.add('hidden');
}

for (let i = 0; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {
  deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click', openWindow);
}

for (let i = 0; i < buttonNo.length; i++) {
  buttonNo[i].addEventListener('click', closeDeleteWindow);
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0px;
}

td,
th {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}

thead th {
  padding: 16px!important;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #abb3c2;
}

.header {
  background-color: #05111A;
  color: white;
}

.table-row {
  height: 65px;
}

.table-download {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #05111A;
}

.table-download i {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.trashIcon {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabelle.css">
  <link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th scope="col">UserID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email Address</th>
        <th scope="col">Standort</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="table-row">
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Audrey Mckinney</td>
        <td>lisa.watson@example.com</td>
        <td>Mannheim</td>
        <td>
          <div class="confirmWindow hidden">
            <p class="confirmWindowText">Are you sure want to delete?</p>
            <button class="buttonYes">Yes</button>
            <button class="buttonNo">No</button>
          </div>
          <button class="trashIcon"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" ></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-row">
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Savannah Howard</td>
        <td>jeff.brown@example.com</td>
        <td>Marburg</td>
        <td>
          <div class="confirmWindow hidden">
            <p class="confirmWindowText">Are you sure want to delete?</p>
            <button class="buttonYes">Yes</button>
            <button class="buttonNo">No</button>
          </div>
          <button class="trashIcon"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" ></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="tabelle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```